# Run two loops simultaneously using multiprocessing module

Tags: python, pandas, python-multiprocessing

I want to run two loops at the same time, I tried using the multiprocessing module but this error was shown:

```
'module' object is not callable
```

This is the code I wrote, is there any way to run both the loops at once?

```
import pandas as pd


for df in pd.read_csv('C:/Users/Workstation/.spyder-py3/AAPL.USUSD_Candlestick_1_M_BID_14.11.2018-28.11.2020 (1).csv',chunksize=14400):
    
    import multiprocessing as mp
    
    df = df[ df["Volume"] != 0]
    
    high_1 =df["High"].iloc[0]
    low_1 =df["Low"].iloc[0]
    
    def loop_high():
        for i in df['High']:
            if i > high_1:
                print('buy')
            break
    
    def loop_low():
        for j in df["Low"]:
            if j< low_1:
                print('sell')
            break
    
    while True:
        mp.process(target = loop_high).start()
        mp.process(target = loop_low).start()
```

Thanks in advance...

Comment: `import threading` and then `Thread1 = threading.Thread(target = loop_low)` and `Thread2 = threading.Thread(target = loop_high)`

Comment: Thank you, but where should I put these statements?

Comment: Why are you looping here? just use a vectorised method

Comment: @Manakin Thank you, but I am a beginner and not familiar with this concept. Could you please give an example like a piece of code.

Comment: @Evorage threading only helps speed up code that releases the GIL. this code does not do that.

Comment: par example : `np.where(df[col] > high, 'Buy', 'Sell')` lots of guides for this, search for where statement pandas dataframe or the sort.

Comment: you can also do `df.High > high_1`

Comment: but printing out buy/sell in a non-deterministic way (in this case, using multiple processes) isn't going to achieve anything of value. what do you actually want to do?

Comment: @acushner I am actually learning Machine Learning and I am doing this for practice. Plus this is just a base, I want to expand on this later...

Comment: @acushner i thought it allowed functions to run in parrarell?

Comment: @Evorage only if they release the GIL. processes can run in parallel, threads only if the GIL is released.